# $r$ identic balls in $n$ boxes, no restrictions per box.

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have $r$ identical balls to be put in $n$ boxes, without any restriction in the number of balls I can put in each box. For example, the following configuration would be one possibility for $10$ balls in $6$  boxes:
[image]

My question is: In how many distinct ways can we do this:

I've tried the following reasoning:

- If $r=0$, we have $1$ possibility.
- If $r=1$, then we have $n$ possibilites (one for each box).
- If $r=2$, then we will have $n$ possibilites for the first ball and $n$ possibilites again for the second, so that would be $n^2$. But we must notice that the balls are identical, and so we divide by $r!$ to avoid multiple counting. So: $n^2/2!$.
- If $r=3$, then we have $n$ possibilities for all the three balls, and hence $n^3$. However since the balls are identical, the total number of possibilities is $n^3/3!$.

In general we would conclude that the total number $N$ would be then
$$N = \frac{n^r}{r!}$$
However, my professor used the generating function method (which is not clear to me WHY it works):
Creating the polynomial:
$$(1+x+x^2+ \cdots +x^r)^n$$
If $r \rightarrow \infty$ and $|x|<1$ this is just a geometric series, $(1-x)^{-n}$. Applying Taylor's expansion gives us:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {n+k-1\choose k} x^k$$
And hence the total number of possibilites would be
$$n+k-1 \choose k$$
**Question:** What is wrong with my reasoning and why it gives incorrect results? Some explanation on why this polynomial method works would also be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let n=2 and r=2.  Your formula gives 2 as the answer, but a direct count gives 3 (2,0),(1,1),(0,2).  Note that for r=2 and n=3 your formula gives 4.5, while the count is 6 (2,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,2),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go back to the case with $r=2$. If you put one ball in the first box and the other in the last one, that is same of starting by putting a ball in the last box and the other in the first. In resume, since the balls are identical you are overcounting.

The best way that I know to solve these problems is following. Assume $r = 5$ balls and $n = 3$ boxes. Then, just like in your picture, one possibility is $$00|00|0$$ which corresponds to 2 balls (zeros) in the first box, 2 in the second and 1 ball in the third box. Basically, we are using | to separate the contents of the boxes. Thus, the number of possibilities comes from how many ways we can change the position of these objects. In this example
$${5+2 \choose 2}$$
and in general
$${n+r-1 \choose n-1} = {n+r-1 \choose r}.$$

Comment: Why isn't this overcounting being removed when I divide the result by $r!$?

Comment: @VitorCGoergen my bad, I didn't see that at first. Then imagine what happens when the two balls are in the same box. That only happens in one specific case, yet you are dividing by $r!$. Thus, in this case, you may in fact be under counting.

Comment: Thanks! Now I see the mistake. I wonder: Is it possible to construct this number of possibilities without moving the objects nor using the polynomial method?

Comment: I also do not understand how you obtained this combination. For me, we have, in this example, 6 different position for each object. But the two of them can be in te same position (meaning an empty box between them).

Comment: @VitorCGoergen yes, it could be $00||000$ meaning, 2, 0 and 3 balls for each box. I think it easier if you see as strings of characters. How many strings of 7 characters are there using five $0$s and two |.

Comment: See also [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).